# Return an Array instead of Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am fetching data from DB like this

```
$endResult = array();

  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    if (!isset($endResult[$row['car']])) {
            $endResult[$row['car']]= (object) array(
              'car' => $row['car'],
              'carModel' => $row['carModel'],
              'colors' => array()
        );
    }

                $endResult[$row['car']] -> colors [] = (object) array(
                    'paintedOn' => $row['paintenOnDate'],
                    'paintedBy' => $row['paintedBy']
                );
            }

//return with slim.php 
$response->body(json_encode($endResult));
```

and result I am getting

```
{"1": 
  {
    "car": "1",
    "carModel": "model-1",
    "colors": [
        {
            "paintedOn": "2014-11-07",
            "paintedBy": "5"
        },{
            "paintedOn": "2014-11-08",
            "paintedBy": "6"
        }]
     },
"2":{
    "car": "2",
    "carModel": "model-2",
    "colors": [
        {
            "paintedOn": "2014-11-09",
            "paintedBy": "7"
        },{
            "paintedOn": "2014-11-10",
            "paintedBy": "8"
        }]
     }
   }//<--replace this with []
```

Even if `$endResult` is declared as Array I am getting {} brackets, how could I replace "Object" brackets with "Array" brackets?

UPDATE: I can't remove `json_encode` as the front-end (backbone) expecting collection

UPDATE 2: `$endResult = array();`  return `[...]`
but this   `$endResult[$row['car']]= (object) array(...)` convert it to `{...}`

Comment: You encode it to json. Json works with `{}`.

Comment: but if I do like this `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` it will return it as `[...]`

Comment: You try `json_decode()` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve what you want because it would result in invalid JSON.  According to [json.org](http://json.org/):

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated by , (comma).

So you can only have *values* in an array.  Because you are adding a name to the value, it must become an object.

If you really want your JSON to be wrapped in an array you need to remove the first-level names, in your example "1" and "2":

```
[
    {
        "car": "1",
        "carModel": "model-1",
        "colors": [
            {
                "paintedOn": "2014-11-07",
                "paintedBy": "5"
            },
            {
                "paintedOn": "2014-11-08",
                "paintedBy": "6"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "car": "2",
        "carModel": "model-2",
        "colors": [
            {
                "paintedOn": "2014-11-09",
                "paintedBy": "7"
            },
            {
                "paintedOn": "2014-11-10",
                "paintedBy": "8"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the conversion to JSON. Also "declaration" in PHP doesn't matter. You can still assign different types in the course of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I think the PHP function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) Should help you here. This turns the JSON format into an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
use json_decode($data,true) for convert returned  data in to array.
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function:

```
$array = array_values($response);
```

Comment: [Um, no.](https://3v4l.org/qBnk0)